# Crystal Reports: Formula to pull data point where other specific criteria are met

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm positive this is a pretty easy formula but I'm quite new to CR and having a difficult time with this...searched SO for my answer but couldn't find it, so please forgive me if this has been asked ad nauseam.

I have a list of patients and each year a patient is assigned a risk score, so each patient has multiple scores.  Data looks something like this:

```
Patient_ID Score_Year Risk_Score
11111      2013       1.05
11111      2014       0.00
22222      2013       0.07
22222      2014       0.11
33333      2013       1.19
33333      2014       0.00
44444      2013       2.13
44444      2014       0.00
55555      2013       0.30
55555      2014       0.54
66666      2013       1.67
66666      2014       2.31
```

I want to create a field that assigns a single risk score for each patient but as you can see from the data, some patients have '0.00' for 2014, which I don't want to include.

My thought was to just create a formula that basically states if [Score_Year] = 2014 and [Risk_Score] <> 0 then ([Risk_Score] where [Score_Year] = 2014) else ([Risk_Score] where [Score_Year] = 2013) but hitting a brick wall.

In a nutshell, I need a formula to pull the 2014 score first but if that is 0 then default to 2013.

Is there a way to write this in a formula or would a select case be better?  That's about the extent of my CR knowledge, so if you guys know of anything more efficient I'd love to learn!

Comment: Which database are you connecting to?

Comment: This is going to sound ridiculous, but I'm not actually 100% sure which database I'm connected to, all data from our clients is ftp'd directly to an outside vendor that handles ETL and database management...we remote into a virtual station on their server and utilize CR from there...it appears to be a SQL OLE DB if that is helpful info?

Comment: It can't hurt to try the queries but you should be able to find a connection string that would tell you which database it is. Obviously you'd want to strip out server names, ip addresses and login information before posting anything on here.

Comment: Actually your 3rd suggestion (// @riskscore) worked perfectly!  I created the grouping as you suggested and dropped your formula into expression builder and tweaked the syntax and updated to my real db field names and it's doing exactly what I had hoped for, thank you Shawnt00!!!!!  I'd upvote your answer but I can't apparently because I don't have 15 rep (new here), but I am very grateful!

Comment: It's not a huge deal but you should be able to accept the answer and I think that might even give you some rep. Glad it worked out :)

Comment: Ugh, I feel dumb...I just noticed the check mark under the upvote ticker to accept the answer, thanks again for your patience and help!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two will probably work as SQL Expressions though it's possible they might be slow. The major benefit is that the calculated values are part of the data set and can be used in all passes of the rendering process.

```
(
select coalesce(max(Score_Year * 1000 + Risk_Score * 100.00) % 1000 / 100.00, 0.00)
from table T2
where (Score_Year <> 2014 or Risk_Score <> 0.00) and T2.Patient_ID = T.Patient_ID
) -- better to say year(getdate()) - 1 instead of hardcoding 2014??
```

This one is less of a hack but would only work on SQL Server (or maybe Sybase). Similar approaches will work for Oracle, DB2, etc.

```
coalesce(
    (    
    select top 1 Risk_Score
    from table T2
    where Risk_Score <> 0.00 and T2.Patient_ID = T.Patient_ID
    order by Score_Year desc
    ),
    0.00
)
```

Here is a Crystal formula that would give the correct value (I'm might be rusty on the syntax though.) You would need to have a Crystal group on Patient_ID and then put the formula in a detail section and suppress it. Then you can use the formula anywhere in the group footer and get back the correct value.

```
// @RiskScore
whileprintingrecords;
static numbervar patient_id :: 0;
static numbervar risk_score := 0.00;
static numbervar score_year := 1900;

    if (
        risk_score = 0.00 and score_year < {T.Score_Year} or
        patient_id <> {T.Patient_ID}
    ) then (
        patient_id := {T.Patient_ID};
        risk_score := {T.Risk_Score};
        score_year := {T.Score_Year};
    )
    risk_score;
```

Following the pattern of the first SQL Expression you could convert that to pair of formulas. The drawback here is that the risk score is not available for use in row level (whilereadingrecords) formulas.

```
// @WeightedRiskScore
{T.Score_Year} * 1000 + {T.Risk_Score} * 100.00;

// @MostRecentRiskScore
max(@WeightedRiskSCore, "Patient_ID") mod 1000 / 100.00;
```

Depending on the specifics of your reports there could possibly be others options.